# Tar file with preserved permissions displays user name for user not on current system

Tags: permissions, tar

How can tar display a user name for example www-data on a system that does not have a www-data user?

I know that tar preserves user permissions based on the system ID in this case www-data being 33 ( I believe?) on Debian systems.

Whats most confusing about this is that if I change the permissions on a folder to 33 a user that does not exist and send it off to another server, tar reports the owner being user 33 but on untaring it the folders are set to owner www-data.

tar (GNU tar) 1.29

Answer (score 1):

This is because `tar` is saving this information too, it's the ustar format specified in POSIX 1003.1-1990. In the offical source code this is specified in the [tar.h header file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/tar.h?h=release_1_29#n23). I copied the important block:

```
/* POSIX header.  */

struct posix_header
{               /* byte offset */
  [...]
  char uid[8];          /* 108 */
  char gid[8];          /* 116 */
  [...]
  char uname[32];       /* 265 */
  char gname[32];       /* 297 */
  [...]
};
```

As you can see the owner user name as well as the owner group name are stored besides the uid and gid.

Answer (score 0):

Tar also saves the name of the user and the group in the file. You can verify this by looking at the tar file itself with tools like `hexdump`.
The reason is that the same name might be used on different systems but with different numbers.

In the second case, the source system doesn't know a name for user 33, so it can't supply a name, just the number. The extracting tar uses this number, and as the system knows this number, it displays a user name for that number.

See also

> --numeric-owner
>   Always use numbers for user/group names.